# How to update a listbox that is bound to a datasource

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following:

```
var listboxchoices = new Dictionary<string, string>();
listboxchoices["color"] = "green";

listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(listboxchoices, null);
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
listBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

To change **listboxchoices["color"]**  to **"blue"** I do:

```
listboxchoices["color"] = "blue";
```

but then how do I get listBox1 to reflect the change?

**[edit]**
Just to add, the list in the listbox is very long and I don't want to reload the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ResetBindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings(v=vs.110).aspx) method to reread all the data from the `BindingSource` and display the updated data in the control.

e.g.

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(listboxchoices, null);
listbox1.DataSource = bs;

// make changes to listboxchoices

bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

Comment: This wont work if the change was made on the listboxchoices. just tried it and it did not update.

Comment: @Anjo are you sure? If you are truly updating the `listboxchoices` reference and not cloning a list `ResetBindings` will cause a re-read of the binding source - this will result in the expected behaviour - do you have an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @Charleh sorry my bad, it did update, but when you try to access the value using ListBox1.SelectedValue, the data being displayed is still the old value

Comment: What are you expecting `SelectedValue` to be after the update?

Comment: should be "blue" since i've updated the original value from "green", but when you check the ListBox1.SelectedValue it will return "green", but when you check the ListBox1.Datasource, the value already updated to "blue"